# JSLint complaining of unused variable when it is used in a while() statement

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, jslint

JSLint is throwing an error of unused `current` even though it is used in the `while()` statement. Obviously my understanding of declaring and using variables is not quite up to scratch. How should I declare and use the variable in this example?

```
var target,
    myFunc;

target = 8;

myFunc = function () {
    // Declare the function's vars
    var i,
        current;

    i = 0;

    while (i < target) {
        current = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable is never read, that's why it is declared "unused".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sirko answered the question in a comment but question shows up as 0 answers in the list so I'll add it as answer.

You set the variable but you never use it (read it). Try the following:

```
while (i < target) {
    current = i;
    console.log(current);
}
```